# How can I list all variables in Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: tensorflow2.0

How can I list all variables in Tensorflow2.0?

Well in Tensorflow1.x, you can just get
`tf.global_variables()` or other similar commands. How can I do the same thing in Tensorflow 2.0?

Comment: Have you tried before asking? please provide reproducible code of any error youencounter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, graph variables are all python objects and you need to keep track of them yourself. see [Effective TF2 -> No More Globals](https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/guide/effective_tf2#no_more_globals)

Comment: Oh, I see. Also, when you define a sequential model you can get the variables from <model-instance>.weights